# Keeping data plus index-data in memory - InnoDB vs. MyISAM

Tags: mysql, database, performance, innodb, myisam

Assume a database consisting of 1 GB of data and 1 GB of index data.

To minimize disk IO and hence maximize performance I want to allocate memory to MySQL so that the entire dataset including indexes can be kept in RAM (assume that the machine has RAM in abundance).

The InnoDB parameter `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is used to specify the size of the memory buffer InnoDB uses to cache data and indexes of its tables. (Note: The memory is used for data **AND** indexes.)

The MyISAM parameter `key_buffer_size` is used to specify the size of the memory buffer MyISAM uses to cache indexes of its tables. (Note: The memory is used **ONLY** for indexes.)

If I want the 2 GB database (1 GB data and 1 GB index) to fit into memory under InnoDB, I'd simply configure the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to be `2GB`. The two gigabytes will hold both the data and the index.

However, when setting the MyISAM key `key_buffer_size` to `2GB` that space will be used for the index, but not for the data.

My questions are:

- Can MyISAM's "data buffer size" (not index data) be configured explicitly?
- When will MyISAM read table data (excluding index data) from disk and when will it read from memory?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- No MyISAM has no general purpose data cache. This is documented in the "key_buffer_size" description from [the official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_key_buffer_size): `This is because MySQL relies on the operating system to perform file system caching for data reads, so you must leave some room for the file system cache.`

Modern OSes, especially Linux, tend to have very smart virtual memory subsystems that will keep frequently accessed files in the page cache, so disk I/O is kept at a bare minimum when the working set fits in available memory.

- So to answer your second question: never.

It's important not to fall into "buffer oversizing" too for the various myisam variables such as read_buffer_size, read_rnd_buffer_size, sort_buffer_size, join_buffer_size, etc as some are dynamically allocated, so bigger doesn't always mean faster - and sometimes it can even be slower - see this [post](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/06/06/are-larger-buffers-always-better/) on mysqlperformanceblog for a very interesting case.

If you're on 5.1 on a posix platform, you might want to benchmark [myisam_use_mmap](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_myisam_use_mmap) on your workload, it's supposed to help high contention cases by reducing the quantity of malloc() calls.