# What does it mean for a MySQL table to fit in main memory?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm seeing phrases like this appear when talking about optimisation of InnoDB tables, but never an explanation of:

- What it means
- How to accomplish it
- The conditions which determine whether it can be accomplished

And also:

- The benefits it brings

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217733/keeping-data-plus-index-data-in-memory-innodb-vs-myisam for questions and answers about configurating this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading a row from disk takes about 100,000 times longer than reading the same row from RAM.

See [Numbers Everyone Should Know](http://everythingisdata.wordpress.com/2009/10/17/numbers-everyone-should-know/), based on an influential keynote presentation by Jeff Dean in 2009. Reading from RAM takes about 100 nanoseconds. A disk seek takes about 10,000,000 nanoseconds (of course some disks are faster, but the best of them are still thousands of times slower than RAM).

Since we typically read data many times, we'd like to avoid the overhead of reading it from disk many times. Thus the first read of data copies the data to RAM, and then subsequent reads take advantage of the faster performance of RAM.

But RAM is volatile (the data in RAM is erased when the computer loses power), and RAM is far more expensive than disk, per unit of storage. So we typically have big disks (for instance 1 TB) to store a lot of data, and a somewhat smaller amount of RAM ([typically 16-64 GB](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/11/02/how-much-memory-do-you-use-to-run-mysql/) on a database server) to store the most frequently-accessed data.

Most of the time, we can assume a relative small subset of your database accounts for the majority of reads. This is called the [Pareto Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle). So even if your RAM is much smaller than your disk, you could assume you can read data that's already in RAM 90% of the time or more.

You can see how well this is working in MySQL:

```
mysql> SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G

...
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
...
Buffer pool hit rate 929 / 1000 ...
...
```

The hit rate of 929 / 1000 indicates that out of 1000 row reads, it was able to read the row in RAM 929 times. The remaining 71 times it had to read the row of data from disk. This is not a bad ratio, but if your frequently-accessed data fits fully in RAM, you'll see this ratio increase to 999 / 1000 or even round up to 1000 / 1000.

You don't necessarily need as much RAM as your whole database -- you just need RAM large enough to satisfy the majority of your queries. Of course more would be better to ensure the last fraction of a percent of queries read data from RAM. It would be nice if we could afford 1000 GB of RAM, but usually it's more cost-efficient to strike a compromise.

---

If you want to learn more, here are some resources:

- https://blogs.oracle.com/mysqlinnodb/entry/data_organization_in_innodb
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html
- [High Performance MySQL, 3rd edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022343.do)
- [Life of a Dirty Page](http://www.percona.com/resources/mysql-videos/life-dirty-page-innodb) presentation by Mark Callaghan (of Google, and later Facebook).

Comment: Thank you Bill. Great write up. You mention that the first read of the data copies the data to the RAM. How can I ensure that when an INSERT or UPDATE is performed it will go straight into the RAM without having to then be read? I am setting innodb_buffer_pool_size to be larger than my database + indexes.

Comment: InnoDB will always write changes to a page in buffer pool. If it needs to load that page first, then it will. If the page is already in the buffer pool, it won't load it again. You don't have to do anything to ensure this.

Comment: So to clarify this for me, if I perform an INSERT query does that get put into the buffer pool/ram there and then? Or does it get put into the ram only after it has been read the first time? I understand it gets put into the buffer once it's been read the first time. I'm not familiar with the "load page" terminology! many thanks.

Comment: I'll try to explain. InnoDB stores data in 16KB pages. Multiple rows can fit on a page. If you want to read, update, or delete a row, InnoDB must read a page from disk into the buffer pool. Likely insert too, but sometimes you may be on the cusp of starting a new pages already because all other pages are full, in which case it won't need to read any page from disk at the time of the insert. Also, insert/update/delete needs to write modified page(s) *back* to disk eventually.

Comment: See list of links to further reading above.

Comment: Thanks so much! Accepted your answer! Already upvoted it. Have a nice day

Comment: I was wondering further about this, is there a setting in mysql which would force an insert that goes into

Comment: Your question seems incomplete. Can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry. I meant, is there a setting in mysql that forces every insert to read the page from the disk, even if the insert means a new page is used?

Comment: No there is not. Why would you want MySQL to load a page from disk unnecessarily? Which page do you think should it load? This idea makes no sense.

Comment: My goal is to ensure every newly inserted row goes straight into the buffer pool. You said it's likely a newly inserted row will but sometimes it's on the cusp of a new page it won't? I am wondering if there is a setting that forces every newly inserted row to go into the buffer. Or is it the case it happens so infrequently that inserted rows dont get put into the buffer straight away that it doesn't matter. You may wonder why I care, but's another story...

Comment: A new page is created first in the buffer pool. You don't need to load it from disk. Pages written remain in the buffer pool until they are later evicted.

Comment: Ah I got it. Thanks for the patient responses! Btw I think users need to sign up or submit a request to watch that Life of a dirty page video

Answer (score 1):

- That means that the table is small enough to be held entirely in RAM
- Buy more RAM or shrink the table (use fewer rows, fewer or smaller columns, and/or fewer or smaller indices)
- It's only possible if the table is small enough to be held entirely in RAM
- RAM is substantially faster that hard drives

Comment: And `entirely` means including indexes.